# What causes timing difference of while loops in python-asyncio

Tags: python, while-loop, python-asyncio

I am trying to run a global clock in a simulation using asyncio. The basic function is just counting  seconds in a eternal while loop and other classes and functions in the simulation can look at the value of the _seconds variable. Now i wanted to write a custom sleep function that waits until the seconds counter has advanced by a certain value:

```
import asyncio
import time
_seconds = 0


def clock():
    global _seconds
    while True:
        _seconds += 1


def sleep(seconds):
    global _seconds
    start = _seconds
    passed = 0
    while _seconds - start < seconds:
        passed += 1
    print(f"internal time passed: {passed}")
    print(f"global time passed: {_seconds - start}")


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
# run in background - None defaults to current loop executor
loop.run_in_executor(None, clock)
```

Now if i call the sleep function i get values for the counter which are much to high and which are very different for the while loop in the sleep function and the global seconds counter, for example:

```
import clock
clock.sleep(100)
>>> "internal time passed: 45784"
>>> "global time passed: 109527"
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

The clock *keeps ticking* between the end of the loop and the calculation of the global duration. Both `print` and string formatting take notable time. Use the global time immediately after the loop.

```py
def sleep(seconds):
    global _seconds
    start = _seconds
    passed = 0
    while _seconds - start < seconds:
        passed += 1
    end = _seconds  # store time when done
    print(f"internal time passed: {passed}")
    print(f"global time passed: {end - start}")
```

Note that `run_in_executor` uses threads, not coroutines. The remaining difference between the two durations is the delay of switching threads by Python and the GIL, not of switching coroutines by `asyncio`.